# How to open a text in the same html page by not creating a same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example, when I open a topic, it would open in the same html page, not redirect to another address:
http://web.archive.org/web/20090409012115/http://www.europeangoldfinch.net/home.htm#

I want to make it exactly like this (clicking on a topic). I downloaded the source files from web archive, but when I click on topic nothing opens up even though the topic text is in that html code.

This is exactly what I want to do:
https://errorsea.com/how-to-change-text-onclick-event-javascript/#Syntax

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the help, I figured it out, I downloaded a website from web.archive.org, and it didn't work well, but I managed to get it working with the javascript included with the website.

Code:

```
#This is the topics# #This is the topics# #This is the topics# #This is the topics# #This is the topics# #This is the topics#
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog0');">FAQ: The Basics Behind the EGF</a></td>
                        <td>KVFinchlover7475</td>
                        <td>02/22</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog1');">US Southwest Sighting???</a></td>
                        <td>KVFinchlover7475</td>
                        <td>03/18</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog2');">Alberta, Canada: Bird Sightings Galore!</a></td>
                        <td>CTfinchforever</td>
                        <td>04/06</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog3');">CTfinchforever? Photos?</a></td>
                        <td>Finchfriend234</td>
                        <td>04/18</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog4');">Paris Finch Symposium?</a></td>
                        <td>FiddlyFinch912</td>
                        <td>04/02</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog5');">Gold Finch Diet</a></td>
                        <td>BobCarduelisIntrigue</td>
                        <td>04/08</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog6');">Cardinal Lovers?</a></td>
                        <td>BigRedCards99</td>
                        <td>04/16</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog7');">Want to start my own birdie site</a></td>
                        <td>KidSpyFinch2343</td>
                        <td>04/21</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog8');">EGF site update!</a></td>
                        <td>KVFinchlover7475</td>
                        <td>06/01</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog9');">New strain of Gold Finch discovered??</a></td>
                        <td>BettyFinchFan483</td>
                        <td>06/03</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog10');">Caring for a pet bird!</a></td>
                        <td>Carol4Christ</td>
                        <td>06/01</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog11');">Ornithology Exhibit in Arizona Museum to feature gold finches!</a></td>
                        <td>FinchesRgr8</td>
                        <td>06/04</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="rowx">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog12');">Gift Ideas</a></td>
                        <td>BirdBrain</td>
                        <td>06/04</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row">
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog13');">Iâ€™ve got a live one!</a></td>
                        <td>Scuderi2000</td>
                        <td>06/06</td>
                        <td align="center"><img src="images/bird_small.gif" width="16" height="19" alt=""></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  
                  
                  
                  
#Below are topic text what should open when clicking on it# #Below are topic text what should open when clicking on it# 
                  <div id="blog0">
                    <table width="636" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8">
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="row">Thread | <a href="#" onclick="resetTopic();">return to list</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="trow">
                        <td colspan="2">FAQ: The Basics Behind the EGF</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>KVFinchlover7475</b><br>
                        02/22<br>
                        6:52pm</td>
                        <td width="509">
                          <p><u>What is a European Gold Finch?</u></p>
                          <p>The EGF is a small passerine bird of the finch family. The EGF is approximately 11-13.5 cm (4-5 inches) long and weighs 16 to 22 grams. Sexes are alike, with a red face, black and snowy white heads, brown and white breast upperparts and black wings with yellow flares. They are simply beautiful!</p>
                          <p><u>Where do they live?</u></p>
                          <p>Typically EGF can be found throughout Europe, northern African and most of Asia. However, they have been spotted in and around Eastern portions of the United States and Northern Canada. In 2005, one was even spotted feeding in Michigan! I hope people will post more sightings here!</p>
                          <p><u>What do EGF typically eat?</u></p>
                          <p>Seeds and insects.</p>
                          <p><u>What is the life expectancy of the EGF?</u></p>
                          <p>5 to 8 years</p>
                          <p><u>Do EGFâ€™s make good pets?</u></p>
                          <p>Yes! How do they ever! EGFâ€™s are kept as cage-birds for their song, which is a very beautiful twittering.</p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div id="blog1">
                    <table width="636" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8">
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="row">Thread | <a href="#" onclick="resetTopic();">return to list</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="trow">
                        <td colspan="2">US Southwest Sighting???</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>KVFinchlover7475</b><br>
                        3/18<br>
                        8:22am</td>
                        <td width="509">Hello fellow European Gold finch enthusiasts! After all the recent sightings of gold finches in the US Midwest over the past couple years, I am almost certain that I saw a Euro goldfinch in Los Lunas, New Mexico. For those of you not familiar with New Mexicoâ€™s geography, thatâ€™s south of Albuquerque. If anyone has seen any other gold finchâ€™s in the nearby southwest area, I would love to hear about it. I have yet to get a picture of one!!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>JumpingBean88</b><br>
                        3/18<br>
                        10:58am</td>
                        <td width="509">No sightings here finchlover, though I did see a Scarlet finch in Arizona once! Very unusual during that time of year!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>GenusEophona</b><br>
                        3/22<br>
                        11:36am</td>
                        <td width="509">Really, are you sure? Iâ€™ve never heard of the Euro gold finches going that far south before in the northern continent. Being that they harken from the rough terrain of Eurasian regions such as Siberia and Mongolia, they generally prefer the colder temperatures. Did the bird appear to be molting when you caught sight of it?</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        3/30<br>
                        12:08pm</td>
                        <td width="509">I have seen the birds in Arizona and Western Texas.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>BettyFinchFan483</b><br>
                        4/05<br>
                        12:29pm</td>
                        <td width="509">F12345S, what sort of finch did you see?</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>GenusEophona</b><br>
                        5/12<br>
                        2:42pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Yes! Very curious to know!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>FISH 40</b><br>
                        5/31<br>
                        3:59pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Bolshoi Booze 6/4<br></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>BirdLover1965</b><br>
                        6/18<br>
                        4:01pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Is anyone attending this yearâ€™s Finch Fest in Portland? My wife and I are contemplating making the 12+ hour drive from San Diego. We are planning on staying at a B&B â€“ and would appreciate any suggestions if you have them.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>BlackbirdApril18</b><br>
                        6/20<br>
                        4:31pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Portland is beautiful this time of year! My suggestion is to camp at Oswald West State Park. Theyâ€™ve got great grounds and plenty of nifty bird watching spots.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>JumpingBean88</b><br>
                        7/01<br>
                        5:58pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Off topic -- I got several great pictures of a momma Cardinal and her baby that landed on my feeder early this morning. The momma was absolutely breathtaking â€“ and her baby a real treat for my dog Oodles and I. Will try and post the pictures a little later on this afternoon when my son gets home â€“ he knows how to work the camera and computer better than I (which is not surprising!)</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div id="blog2">
                    <table width="636" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8">
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="row">Thread | <a href="#" onclick="resetTopic();">return to list</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="trow">
                        <td colspan="2">Alberta, Canada: Bird Sightings Galore!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        04/06<br>
                        9:42pm</td>
                        <td width="509">
                          <p>I recently returned from a bird watching trip in Alberta, Canada with my seniorâ€™s group. 5 days of Snow Geese, Brants, Red-throated Loons and Western Grebe!! I was in heaven! And Grant, a good friend of mine who accompanied us, took some amazing photographs including a Yellow Rail, Northern Bobwhite and Ruddy Duck! Who would of thought? Now Iâ€™m worn out and preparing for my grandsonâ€™s church play this evening.</p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>TrainsetMan</b><br>
                        04/08<br>
                        10:10am</td>
                        <td width="509">That sounds like an amazing trip, CTFF! Years ago my wife and I have often talked of visiting Canada to do some bird watching ourselves but we never got around to it. Sadly, Irma passed away three years ago so we were never able to take our trip. Iâ€™ve heard Alberta can be quite nippy this time of year. I hope you stayed warm.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        04/23<br>
                        7:16pm</td>
                        <td width="509">TrainsetMan -- I hope youâ€™ll still consider taking the trip. I know your wife would love nothing more for you then to witness Godâ€™s magnificent creatures in their natural habitat. God bless you.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Scuderi2000</b><br>
                        05/08<br>
                        9:12pm</td>
                        <td width="509">I am taking a bird watching trip of my own this Summer to Great Britain. Itâ€™ll be my first time to Europe since the early 70â€™s and my first experience with EGFâ€™s in the wild. My daughter and her husband are taking me as part of a motherâ€™s day present.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        05/09<br>
                        7:44am</td>
                        <td width="509">You will love G.B., Scuderi2000! If you get an opportunity, be sure to check out the Beak Nâ€™ Feathers store in London. Itâ€™s a small shop for bird enthusiasts and they have the most amazing collection of songbirds you will ever see in one place. Have a great trip and please let me know if you were able to make it to Beak Nâ€™ Feathers.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div id="blog3">
                    <table width="636" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8">
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="row">Thread | <a href="#" onclick="resetTopic();">return to list</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="trow">
                        <td colspan="2">CTfinchforever? Photos?</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Finchfriend234</b><br>
                        04/18<br>
                        6:42pm</td>
                        <td width="509">
                          <p>CTfinchforever. I havenâ€™t made it our West yet, but I hear the goldfinch against the backdrop of the Rockies is breathtaking. Do you have any photos? Maybe we can swap. Let me know.</p>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        04/19<br>
                        7:32am</td>
                        <td width="509">As you know, Finchfriend234, the finch is hard to capture on film, but I do have many other birds (cardinal, bluejay, etc.) against the backdrop of the Rockies. Would these interest you? What do you have?</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Goldgoddess67</b><br>
                        04/27<br>
                        7:15pm</td>
                        <td width="509">Does anyone out there know why the gold finch has a red face? Is it to protect itself from predators? Or just to look pretty for all of us. LOL!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Finchfriend234</b><br>
                        04/28<br>
                        4:22pm</td>
                        <td width="509">The red face is just to look pretty! :) A natural beauty.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Goldgoddess67</b><br>
                        04/29<br>
                        7:36pm</td>
                        <td width="509">I agree!</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>Finchforlife</b><br>
                        04/30<br>
                        6:36am</td>
                        <td width="509">As you all should know, calling yourselves FINCH LOVERSâ€¦ the red face is for mating. The male finch is attracted to it. CTfinchforever, I would like to see some of your other photos.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="prow">
                        <td width="127"><b>CTfinchforever</b><br>
                        05/01<br>
                        11:36am</td>
                        <td width="509">Letâ€™s trade email information, Finchforlife.</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript if you want to modify the current page instead of loading a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand want you actually want but from the look of things, if I'm correct you want to use a `#URL` system in your page. So I assume you want the page viewport to be on `blog0` **div** when the user clicks on

```
<td>
   <a href="#" onclick="showTopic('blog0');">
    FAQ: The Basics Behind the EGF
   </a>
</td>
```

if that is the case then you can this instead:

```
<td>
   <a href="#blog0">
    FAQ: The Basics Behind the EGF
   </a>
</td>
```